# JavaScript: привязка контекста

Tags: javascript

При выполнении этого блока кода, выведется undefined, а не 'Вася', так как setTimeout получил метод user.sayHi, но не ее контекст:

```
var user = {
  firstName: "Вася",
  sayHi: function() {
    alert( this.firstName );
  }
};

setTimeout(user.sayHi, 1000); // undefined (не Вася!)
```

А если вызов метода обернуть в анонимную функцию, то выведется 'Вася'.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  user.sayHi(); // Вася
}, 1000);
```

Собственно возник вопрос: почему при оборачивании вызова метода в анонимную функцию, то контекст появляется?

Comment: Порядок вызова не перепутан? В JS действует "поднятие кода". Если не секрет, покажите весь код

Comment: потому что он Вы его сами написали: `user.`

Comment: @Igor ему ↓ стало стыдно)

Comment: @DNS https://jsfiddle.net/g5dxxfn0/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ему было бы еще стыднее, если бы он знал, что ответ и комментарии все равно видны :).

Comment: Тут просто пропущены скобки `setTimeout(user.sayHi(), 1000);`

Comment: @DNS Поставьте время, скажем, 5 секунд.

Comment: @DNS так же отвечал Igor) после вызова со скобками функция setTimeout начинает работать некорректно

Comment: @Igor проверил на 5,7,10 сек. Надо больше? Все ОК

Comment: @Марсель - `setTimeout` работает нормально, просто туда подается  `undefined`

Comment: @DNS Все не ОК. Да, надо больше. Вы чего-то не замечаете.

Comment: @Igor, я ж своими глазами вижу - ОК для 1,5,7,10 сек

Comment: @DNS И что, `alert` появляется через 10 секунд?

Comment: Не засекал.... Но пользовался платформой из ссылки.

Comment: @DNS https://jsfiddle.net/g5dxxfn0/1/

Comment: @DNS Ну, разница между "десять секунд" и "мгновенно" достаточно очевидна.

Comment: Да, вспомнил, это области видимости (пространства имен). Есть [поучающий пример](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/make-army). Сорри, праздники... Кстати, с прошедшим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без оборачивания в анонимную функцию this становится равен window.

```
var user = {
  firstName: "Вася",
  sayHi: function() {
    alert( this.firstName );
    console.log(this) // Window {}
  }
};

setTimeout(user.sayHi, 1000);
```

С оборачиванием this равен объекту:

```
var user = {
  firstName: "Вася",
  sayHi: function() {
    alert( this.firstName );
    console.log(this) // Object {firstName: "Вася"}
  }
};

setTimeout(() => user.sayHi(), 1000);
```

Можно вручную установить this вызовом функции через func.call(context, arg1, arg2...)

Все дело в том, что коллбэку setTimeout передается только сама функция, без ее контекста.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `bind`;

```
var user = {
  firstName: "Вася",
  sayHi: function() {
    alert( this.firstName );
  }
};

setTimeout(user.sayHi.bind(user), 1000); // undefined (не Вася!)
```

контекст меняется лишь потому, что контекст равен (вне случая bind) тому что написано до точки перед вызываемой функцией.

```
  my.pretty.good.object.method();
  //               /|\
  //----------------| контекст
```

если до точки ничего нет, то глобальному объекту или `undefined` в случае `"use strict";`

Comment: не-е-ет, "еще и так" нельзя - что будет сначала, курица или яйцо?

Comment: проверил. Вы в правой части присвоения используете переменную, стоящую слева. Чему она равна в момент вызова `bind`?

Comment: Второй вариант не работает. Пруф: https://jsfiddle.net/830qujLy/

Comment: секунду, вы в общем правы, но что-то странное

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Не надо доказательств. Вы ведем умозрительную беседу :), академический спор - "как у Ивана Тургенева - все сидят и спорят про любовь".

Comment: @Igor, а я прагматик. Проще один раз попробовать, чем "умозрительно беседовать".

Comment: всё разобрался, просто user у меня уже был дефайнен :) двойной вызов объявления.

Comment: @zb', `const` вам в помощь ;)

Comment: я знаю, или let, не важно, в консоли просто слегка неудобен