# Java script, jquery, Не работает код с книги

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Пишу код по книге, написал все как там. Потом дали задание заанимировать машинку с помощью setInterval. Но они перемещаются только один раз на 5 пикселей, а должны каждые 30 мили-секунд.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var Car = function (x, y) {
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
};

Car.prototype.draw = function() {
var carImg = '<img src="img/logo.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 
100px;">';
this.carElement = $(carImg);
this.carElement.css({
    position: "absolute",
    left: this.x,
    top: this.y
});

$('body').append(this.carElement);
};

Car.prototype.moveRight = function() {
this.x += 5;
this.carElement.css ({
    left: this.x,
    top: this.y
});
};

var nissan = new Car(100, 100);
var kia = new Car(200, 200);

nissan.draw();
kia.draw();

setInterval(nissan.moveRight(), 20);
setInterval(kia.moveRight(), 30);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

тут:

```
setInterval(nissan.moveRight(), 20);
setInterval(kia.moveRight(), 30);
```

ты вызываешь методы сразу, а нужно передавать ссылку на них:

```
setInterval(nissan.moveRight, 20);
setInterval(kia.moveRight, 30);
```

Причем произойдет, скорее всего, потеря контекста. На что он сменится, пример его и как с ней бороться можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/661129/191482), а также  полном ответе [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535030/191482)

Comment: тогда идет такая ошибка:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined
    at Car.moveRight (script.js:35)

Comment: @Horchynskyi добавил... в первой ссылке аналогичная проблема, во второй - полное описание этой проблемы